# why the magento is generating this custom redirects

Tags: magento-1.8, url-rewrite

why the magento is generating this custom redirects in **URL Rewrite Management.**

Please find the below image:
 [image]

Thanks

Comment: is that a configurable product?

Comment: it is simple product

Comment: but... a configurable child?

Comment: in this site their is no configurable products only simple products and one bundle product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a **configurable/simple** based catalog, this is a common issue in Magento 1.* (I think it is fixed since some version of 1.9)

Take a look at [this](http://tooschee.com/disable-simple-product-url-rewrite-management-in-magento/)

Basically, it has no sense to assign an url to non visible products, as it typically happens for simple products, when they are a configurable child

If that's not your case, then it should probably start to avoid **url duplication** (more than 1 simple product has the same name, so the same url) in your catalog, and reindex process adds new redirects every time it is executed. Take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/edannenberg/5310008) then

Comment: in default magento-1.9.3.4 https://prnt.sc/hnt3o2 and magento-1.9.3.6 https://prnt.sc/hnt56w also creating custom  url rewrite after reindex

Comment: Use the second link then

Comment: feel free to mark answer as valid, if it helped ;)